# Optional argument to \item in enumitem list

Tags: lists, enumitem

I'm trying to set up a list environment for typesetting a problem set.  I'd like to be able to input something like the following:

```
\begin{pset}
\item First solution.
\item[2.2] Second solution.
\end{pset}
```

and have it come out as:

```
Problem 1. First solution.
Problem 2 (2.2). Second solution
```

with the optional argument to `\item` being typeset in parentheses if it's present.  I assume I should be able to `\renewcommand{\makelabel}` somehow, but I can't figure out how to do it.  I can't get anything like the following to work:

```
\newcommand{\makepsetlabel}[1]{some if/then involving #1, checking if empty}
\newlist{pset}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[pset]{
   before={\renewcommand\makelabel[1]{\makepsetlabel{##1}}
}
```

What's the right way?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use a different command instead of `\item`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{pset}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[pset]{
  label=Problem \arabic*\protect\thispitem,
  ref=\arabic*,
  align=left
}
\newcommand{\pitem}[1][]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \def\thispitem{.}%
  \else
    \def\thispitem{ (#1).}%
  \fi
  \item}

\begin{document}

\begin{pset}
\pitem First
\pitem[2.2] Second
\end{pset}

\end{document}
```

In the label I add a command `\thispitem` (with `\protect` so `enumitem` doesn't interpret it when setting up the environment).

Then `\pitem` examines the presence of an optional argument and acts consequently: if none is specified, it just prints a period, otherwise a space, the parenthesized argument and the period.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a good way to go -- thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Suppose you modify `\label` so as to omit the `Problem ` part. How can you get the item numbers in the `pset` list to be indented the same amount as the items in an ordinary `enumerate`?

Comment: @murray Compute a suitable value for `itemindent`.

Comment: @egreg: Calculate the value for `itemindent` from what? I want the indent to be the same as the default for `enumerate`.

Comment: @murray The problem is that the default uses right-aligned labels.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to grab the optional argument using your own command, so that `\item` does not see it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\myitem[1][\relax]{\item\ifx#1\relax\else(#1)\fi}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\myitem abc
\myitem[2.1] def
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The period will be in the wrong place.

Comment: @egreg --- Friday night is not the time to consider such details!

Comment: @IanThompson: I've added a deleted answer that could be used as a slight improvement(?) to your current definition. Grab some from it if you need it.