# How to create a enumerate list adding a custom prefix before each item number?

Tags: lists, enumerate, enumitem, description

I found this question [Adding some common text to enumerated description lists](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/352019/adding-some-common-text-to-enumerated-description-lists) to be the closest:

> ```
> \documentclass{scrbook}
>
> \usepackage{enumitem}
> \newcounter{descriptcount}
> \newlist{enumdescript}{description}{1}
> \setlist[enumdescript,1]{%
>   before={\setcounter{descriptcount}{0}%
>           \renewcommand*\thedescriptcount{\arabic{descriptcount}}},
>         font={\bfseries\stepcounter{descriptcount}Case \thedescriptcount,~}
> }
>
> \begin{document}
>
> \begin{enumdescript}
>    \item item one
>    \item item two
>    \item[Some Text] item three
>    \item item four
>    \item item five
> \end{enumdescript}
> \end{document}
> ```
>
> [image]

---

The only difference, it that I would like to put the number after the custom text, and not before, i.e., instead of doing:

```
Case 1, item one
Case 2, item two
Case 3, Some Text item three
Case 4, item four
Case 5, item five
```

I would like to do:

```
\begin{enumdescript}
   \item[Some first] item one
   \item[Some second] item two
   \item[Some third] item three
   \item[Some forth] item four
   \item[Some Fifth] item five
\end{enumdescript}
```

```
Some first 1) item one
Some second 2) item two
Some third 3) item three
Some forth 4) item four
Some fitth 5) item five
```

---

Related questions:

1. [Illegal parameter number in definition of \enit@before. You meant to type ## instead of #, right?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/512141/illegal-parameter-number-in-definition-of-enitbefore-you-meant-to-type-ins/)
2. [How to fix Illegal parameter number in definition of a new Tikz command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367918/how-to-fix-illegal-parameter-number-in-definition-of-a-new-tikz-command)
3. [Enumerated description list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30029/enumerated-description-list)
4. [Intertext like command in enumerate environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135726/intertext-like-command-in-enumerate-environment)
5. [Adding some common text to enumerated description lists](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/352019/adding-some-common-text-to-enumerated-description-lists)
6. [Optional argument to \item in enumitem list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97431/optional-argument-to-item-in-enumitem-list)
7. [Insert a space after a command: {}, vs \ , vs \space](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/362046/insert-a-space-after-a-command-vs-vs-space)
8. [What is the difference in citing/referencing with or without tilde?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41264/what-is-the-difference-in-citing-referencing-with-or-without-tilde)
9. [What commands are there for horizontal spacing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74353/what-commands-are-there-for-horizontal-spacing)
10. [When should I use non-breaking space?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15547/when-should-i-use-non-breaking-space)
11. [Difference between control space and non-breaking space](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59259/difference-between-control-space-and-non-breaking-space)

---

Other questions:

1. [Difference between control space and non-breaking space](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59259/difference-between-control-space-and-non-breaking-space)
2. [Combining newcommand and renewcommand with optional arguments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/360910/combining-newcommand-and-renewcommand-with-optional-arguments)
3. [When to use \LetLtxMacro?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88001/when-to-use-letltxmacro)
4. [How to redefine the caption command with optional arguments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17504/how-to-redefine-the-caption-command-with-optional-arguments)
5. [Optional parameter in newcommand](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279434/optional-parameter-in-newcommand)
6. [Creating new counter formats on-the-fly with enumitem's \AddEnumerateCounter*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302716/creating-new-counter-formats-on-the-fly-with-enumitems-addenumeratecounter)
7. [correct usage of \@namedef and \@nameuse](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126273/correct-usage-of-namedef-and-nameuse)
8. [What is the difference between \let and \def?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258/what-is-the-difference-between-let-and-def)
9. [enumitem package and description lists](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56249/enumitem-package-and-description-lists)
10. [How do I change the `enumerate` list format to use letters instead of the default Arabic numerals?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2291/how-do-i-change-the-enumerate-list-format-to-use-letters-instead-of-the-defaul)
11. [Redefine the bullets of the enumerate environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267814/redefine-the-bullets-of-the-enumerate-environment)
12. [LaTex enumitem - controlling alignment of items by level](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/457059/latex-enumitem-controlling-alignment-of-items-by-level)
13. [How to remove space at the start of inline enumitem itemized list?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/471121/how-to-remove-space-at-the-start-of-inline-enumitem-itemized-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution: I create a new environment, which first redefines the `\makedescriptionlabel` command, then enters a description environment.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xparse}
\newcounter{descriptcount}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{enumdescript}{O{}}{%
    \setcounter{descriptcount}{0}%
    \renewcommand*\descriptionlabel[1]{%
      \stepcounter{descriptcount}%
      \normalfont\bfseries ##1~\arabic{descriptcount})%
    }%
    \description%
  }%
  {\enddescription}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumdescript}
   \item[Some first] item one
   \item[Some second] item two
   \item[Some third] item three
   \item[Some fourth] item four
   \item[Some Fifth] item five
\end{enumdescript}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What is this `O{}` passed as argument to `\NewDocumentEnvironment`? Or where I can find the documentation for this `\NewDocumentEnvironment`? I keep searching but I cannot find it.

Comment: I just found it. It is from the `xparse` package: **`O As for o, but returns (default) if no value is given. Should be given as O{(default)}`**