# How to recognize the enumerate shortlabels in my custom environment?

Tags: lists, environments, enumerate, enumitem, xparse

On [How to create a enumerate list adding a custom prefix before each item number?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/512123/how-to-create-a-enumerate-list-adding-a-custom-prefix-before-each-item-number) I learned how to create a custom environment to create labels. But now, it is missing the `enumitem` shortlabels feature:

By taking the original example, I managed to pass the delimiter type to the nested environment list:
[image]

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xparse}
\newcounter{enumerateoptionalcount}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{enumerateoptional}{O{)}}{%
    \setcounter{enumerateoptionalcount}{0}%
    \renewcommand*\descriptionlabel[1]{%
      \stepcounter{enumerateoptionalcount}%
      \normalfont\bfseries ##1~\arabic{enumerateoptionalcount}#1%
    }%
    \description%
  }%
  {\enddescription}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerateoptional}[)]
   \item[Some first] item one
   \item[Some second] item two
   \item[Some third] item three
   \item[Some fourth] item four
   \item[Some Fifth] item five
\end{enumerateoptional}

\end{document}
```

But how can I also pass the number type as `enumerate` environment has, i.e.,

1. If I call `\begin{enumdescript}[1)]`, then, the number are `1) ..., 2) ...`
2. If I call `\begin{enumdescript}[i)]`, then, the number are `i) ..., ii) ...`
3. If I call `\begin{enumdescript}[I)]`, then, the number are `I) ..., II) ...`
4. ...

I tried to look at the [`enumitem` package source-code](https://github.com/jbezos/enumitem/blob/1bdcad0987823b3716c86b126b3863f895ea9c4a/enumitem.sty#L568-L588), but I cannot understand anything about it. For example, `\ifx\enit@b\enit@c\else ... \enit@elt{##1}{##2}`, what is `enit`? What does `elt` mean? What are `enit@a`, `enit@b`, `enit@c` doing?

```latex
\newcommand\SetEnumerateShortLabel[2]{%
  \let\enit@a\@empty
  \def\enit@elt##1##2{%
    \def\enit@b{#1}\def\enit@c{##1}%
    \ifx\enit@b\enit@c\else
      \expandafter\def\expandafter\enit@a\expandafter{%
        \enit@a
        \enit@elt{##1}{##2}}%
    \fi}%
  \enit@marklist
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\enit@a\expandafter{%
    \enit@a
    \enit@elt{#1}{#2}}%
  \let\enit@marklist\enit@a}

\SetEnumerateShortLabel{a}{\alph*}
\SetEnumerateShortLabel{A}{\Alph*}
\SetEnumerateShortLabel{i}{\roman*}
\SetEnumerateShortLabel{I}{\Roman*}
\SetEnumerateShortLabel{1}{\arabic*}
```

Comment: Why do you reimplement the `enumerate` environment instead of using the one provided by `enumitem`? You could just pass the optional parameter to it then.

Comment: Because I did not know I could use it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify the code in the OP by using tools from the [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package to create a customised enumerate environment. If you do this then you can change the labels in the enumerate in standard way provided by the [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package:

```
\begin{enumerateoptional}[label=\alph*]
   \item[Some first] item one
   \item[Some second] item two
   \item[Some third] item three
   \item[Some fourth] item four
   \item[Some Fifth] item five
\end{enumerateoptional}
```

to produce:

[image]

whereas by default, when you omit the `[label=\alph*]`, you get:

[image]

The trick is to redefine the `\item` command to do what you want. To do this I make a "copy" of the real item command and then define a custom `\optionalItem` that gives your format. Then in the specifications for the custom enumerate environment you add `before=\let\item\optionalItem` to use the custom item command.

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{enumerateoptional}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[enumerateoptional]{
    before=\let\item\optionalItem,
    label=\arabic*,
    nosep,
    labelindent=20mm,
    leftmargin=*
}
\let\realItem\item

\newcommand\optionalItem[1][]{%
  \refstepcounter{enumerateoptionali}% increment the counter
  \realItem[\bfseries#1~\theenumerateoptionali)]%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerateoptional}
   \item[Some first] item one
   \item[Some second] item two
   \item[Some third] item three
   \item[Some fourth] item four
   \item[Some Fifth] item five
\end{enumerateoptional}

\begin{enumerateoptional}[label=\alph*]
   \item[Some first] item one
   \item[Some second] item two
   \item[Some third] item three
   \item[Some fourth] item four
   \item[Some Fifth] item five
\end{enumerateoptional}

\end{document}
```